# iptables rule that uses state

Tags: 18.04, iptables

I tried the command `conntrack -E` and it returns nothing on Ubuntu 18.04.

Someone told me that I have some iptables rule that uses state stuff.

So I set iptables rule such as below:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Then conntrack works for me on 18.04.

I wonder why I have to set iptables rule. 
Why does it work on the other ubuntu version like 16.04 or 14.04 without adding iptables rule?

What is modified on 18.04?

Comment: I only used a rule that uses state stuff to be sure that all the right modules got loaded. You can flush the rules after, and conntrack will still work. However, I don't know why this is needed in the first place. It's the same on 17.10.